# emiting an event with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have 2 apps,and they are running in 2 different Servers(working with NodeJS), and they are connecting with each other via socket.io-client.
what i want is that :

1. sned a msg via a Socket from my web page to the Server A.
2. when the Server A reciev the msg from the web page. he send it back to the Server B with have the Socket.io-client.

the exchange between the 2 server work fin,but when i reciev a socket from the web page a try to resend it to the other server nothing hapen.
well that's my code:

**server A:**

```js
socket.on("ice",(msg)=>{
  //when i reciev a msg i send it back to the other app
  socket.emit("Rice",msg)
})
```

**server B:**

```js
var ioc = require('socket.io-client');
var s = ioc.connect("http://localhost:8000/", {reconnection: true});

s.on('connect', function () {
  s.on('Rice',(msg)=>{
      console.log('ice : '+ msg)
  })
});
```

Comment: `socket.emit("Rice",msg)` in your first code block is sending the message back to the client from where the "ice" message came.

Comment: I thought the same thing, so I will have to store the data in a variable and send it to the other server!!

Comment: you need two channels, one channel between servers and the other between server A and client(s). When Server A receives message, forward the message onto the other channel.

Comment: how i do that !!! can you provied me a tuto or an exemple !!

Comment: Can you show the code where serverA receives the connection from serverB?